# Add unique values from an array to another JS

Tags: javascript, loops, object, arrayobject

Let's say I got an array of objects like this:

```
let arrayOfObjects = [{Name: "A", Number: "1"} {Name: "A", Number: "2"} {Name: "B", Number: "2"} {Name: "A", Number: "2"}]
```

How can I loop through this, and add the unique values of "Number" to a new array? So the desired new array would be:

```
let newArray: [1,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let newArray = [...new Set(arrayOfObjects.map(el => parseInt(el.Number)))]
```